# How do I add a stop process command to my bot, which ends the on-going command? (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I want to add a joke command to my Discord bot, something like `bt!donotusethis` which will then answer with the command itself, causing an infinite spam chain.

Obviously, this needs a command to stop it. I want to add a command such as `bt!stop`, which will end the spam.

Is there any way to add this?

I tried using this:

```
   client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
     if (message.content.startsWith("bt!donotusethis")) {
       message.channel.send("bt!donotusethis");
     }
   });

   client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
     if (message.content.startsWith("bt!stop")) {
       //this is where the end process command goes
     }
   });
```

And instead of the `//this is where the end process command goes` I added `client.process.end` which did stop the spam, but also crashed the bot itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `client.process.end` is not a function of Discord.js that's why the bot crashes. If you want to stop the bot, you can add a spamming variable with the data "false". When the command is run, you can set it to true and when the other command is run you can set it to false. And also remove multiple `messageCreate` event

Here's a code sample:

```js
let spamming = false;

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("bt!donotusethis")) {
    if (!spamming) {
      spamming = true;
      message.channel.send("bt!donotusethis");
    } else {
      message.channel.send("bt!donotusethis");
    }
  } else if (message.content.startsWith("bt!stop")) {
    spamming = false;
  }
});
```

Comment: How do I remove/stop the `messageCreate` event? I messed around with the code a bit but it didn't return any results.
I tried adding a separate block of code:
(sorry for the wonky look)

`client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
     if (message.content.startsWith("bt!stop")) {
       spamming = false;
       message.channel.send("**Spamming stopped.**");
     }
     });`

Comment: @Evan
In that case, you have to send the message before setting the spamming to false, here's the updated code

`client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {      if (message.content.startsWith("bt!stop")) {   message.channel.send("**Spamming stopped.**");   spamming = false   }      });`